# Unable to add Term in Termset using REST API

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, taxonomy

I am trying to add term in termset using REST API in my SPFX solution.
But I am getting 403 error,.
Please help what is wrong with the below code,

My account got added in term store admin.
Also, using same rest api I was able to add term from Power automate.(so, no permission issue).

Note: Due to version mismatch, I am unable to use PNP/sp-taxanomy

PFB my code.

````
let restapi = siteUrl + '/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/{group-id}/sets/{termset-id}/children';
        let body: string =JSON.stringify({"labels": [{"name": "AI Innovation","isDefault":true,"languageTag": "en-US"}],"descriptions": [{"description": "AI Innovation","languageTag": "en-US"}]});
        body = body.substring(1, body.length - 1);
        body = '{' + body + '}';
        context.spHttpClient.post(restapi,
            SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
            {
                headers: {
                     'Content-type': 'application/json'
                     //'odata-version': '',
                    // 'IF-MATCH': '*',
                    // 'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE'
                },
                body: body
            })
            .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): void => {
                console.log(response);
            }, (error: any): void => {
                console.log(error);
            });```
````

Comment: Could you share exact API Url which you are using?

Comment: added url in desc.